# Is it possible to access a variable from a class's __init__ by a function from the same class?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter

I want to change the text in a status box when the user clicks a button.  The current status when the page is initiated is "no file loaded", after clicking a button, I'd like the text on this button to change to show that "file has loaded" or some such.

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
       
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Load Data from Files", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        invButton = tk.Button(self, text="Load Inventory Data", command = self.openFile)
        invButton.pack()
        invStatusText = tk.StringVar()
        invStatusText.set("No file selected") 
        invStatus = tk.Button(self, state='disabled')
        invStatus.config(textvariable=invStatusText)
        invStatus.pack()
      
    def openFile(self):
        name = fd.askopenfilename()
        self.invStatusText.set("File Loaded")
```

When I've ran this without passing self to openFile() and it trips up when entering the openFile function with the message `NameError: name 'invStatusText' is not defined`. I've got closer when using self (the code above).  In this case I get the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-6-99355e7afb55>", line 84, in openFile1
    self.invStatusText.set("File Loaded")
AttributeError: 'PageOne' object has no attribute 'invStatusText'
```

So I'd like to change the text of the button invButton by changing the value of a variable held in the `__init__` function but it's not letting me.  I saw elsewhere (I have about 20 stackOverflow tabs open) that these variables should be defined at the class level, outside of `__init__` but when I tried to put invStatusText inside of the class I got the message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `__init__` you need to make the attribute you want to call an instance attribute (by adding self to it):

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
       
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.invStatusText.set("No file selected") 
        ...
      
    def openFile(self):
        name = fd.askopenfilename()
        self.invStatusText.set("File Loaded")
```

Also I'd like to point out that you are normally not meant to do things in `__init__`. Make a separate method to create UI rather than doing it there. As your UI grows, your `__init__` will become incomprehensible.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, and I will be using the tip about creating a createUI method to do all this type of stuff, much appreciated.